Problems authenticating the API in one of the Salesforce accounts
We are experiencing an issue connecting to the Salesforce API in our production base. When trying to log in via a custom domain and grant permissions to the App in our account, we received an error.
enter image description here
We are unable to authorize you due to an OAuth error. 1814: An unexpected error occurred during authentication. Please try again
However, we didn’t spend much time on the login screen…
And when we try to log in through the environment's home screen to grant permissions to the App, it keeps loading infinitely.
The app is working correctly in other Salesforce accounts we have and even in the sandbox account.
What could be happening?
Authenticate with the Salesforce API

There might be error code / some detail in the URL, try googling what's in it. And do you see any errors in login history? Normal login with sf username/pass or some single sign on?
